# CPU Load in MHz

Tags: embedded

I have been going through some articles on benchmarking for uC (Cortex M from ARM) where it is often mentioned that the application has a CPU Load. Now I do understand CPU load in terms of a % of CPU utilization. However some of the articles or benchmarks is in terms of MHz. This is not very clear as to how the CPU load in MHz is benchmarked, since a lot of the uC I have worked with have a different benchmark score based on the architecture of the uC and the operating frequency.

Any information or insight would be very useful.

Comment: I'd say that CPU load is not expressible in MHz, and any attempt to do so is both silly and prima facie evidence of cluelessness.

Comment: I doubt this is a suitable question for SO but you should at least include links to the source of your information. It is either flawed, or you are misinterpreting the data.  CPU load only makes any sense in a multi-threaded/tasking environment as the proportion of time spent not in the idle task.

Comment: mips maybe (millions of instructions per second) but not mhz.  Understand that benchmarking in general has limited value, adding a single nop to your code can change the performance by as much as 10% depending on the situation.  same source code subtle compiler option differences, or using a different compiler can have even more dramatic affects from tens of percent to several times faster or slower.  same hardware same code.   same hardware rearranging the functions in the code, or adding or removing a line, dramatic affects.  so what is it you are really interested in?

Comment: even same binary on so called compatible systems has only limited value as well.  doesnt mean the slower system in that test is generally slower, the answer will always be "it depends".

Comment: As an example of the link is the following document where they have evaluated Speex Vocoder Performance [link](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00073742.pdf). The Section of interest is 1.6

Comment: just above the section in the app note you called out, it says numbers were taking against a 168MHz system clock.  So maybe Load (MHz) is meant to mean a raw number of the 168 million system clock 'ticks', taken per second, used to run that codec.  In other words, 168MHz = 100% CPU, 84MHz=50% CPU?  If that's the case, this is a really bizarre measurement.

Comment: The case were such a measurement would make sense (maybe?) is if you intend to run the CPU at a different clock rate than specified.  So if an operation requires 10.0 million clock ticks worth of CPU time per second, you know you cannot clock the CPU core slower than 10MHz, and if it were clocked at say... 20MHz, you are using 50% of your CPU assuming this all scales linearly for the architecture you're on.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. So CPU load in MHz would mean that if the CPU is running at 100MHz and an operation completes in 10ms it would effectively mean that 1MHz is the CPU load considering the number of ticks.